# pyspark Text data source does not support boolean data type.;

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am generating schema dynamically and has data as below:

```
name    present  country
hari     0     USA
Sally    1      Germany
Tella.  1.      Austarlia
```

df= spark.read.format(text).load('a.txt',schema=schema)

```
error:  Text data source does not support boolean data type.;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is expected. Text means that Spark does not know what is in there. It can be anything. Each line/file is read as a *String* (please see [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-text.html#text-files)).

However, for your data it seems it would be better to use *.csv* format, for both exporting the dynamically generated data to a file (ex: *a.csv*), and then reading it using `format("csv")`